# Why does this line in my fstab give me an "Invalid Argument" error

Tags: linux, fstab, cifs, fuse

Here's the entry in my fstab that's giving me a `mount error(22): Invalid argument` error.

```
//{address}/networkshare /mnt/pslive-netshare cifs umask=077,gid=1000,uid=1000,credentials=/root/.pslivecred,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

Note that `{address}` is replaced with the actual address of the host.

Comment: I think the umask=077 is giving you the problem.

Comment: I also tried `umask=0077`, with the same result.

Comment: remove umask altogether, I do not think you can use umask with cifs (samba) mounts.

Comment: You should *accept* the answer provided, if it solved your issue. It will be useful to other people searching for a solution to the same problem among previous questions.

Comment: I accepted the answer, but he left the comment that solved my issue before he left the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the "umask" option altogether, it is not a valid option with CIFS mounts.